# Edit an item zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework2, edit

I want to edit something when i click on the edit button.

so I made a foreach in my edit.phtml view to display some data. i also put them in a table.

This is the edit.phtml :

```
<table class="table table-hover">

    <?php

    foreach($foods as $row) : ?>
        <tr>

            <td class="food_id"><?php echo $row->kindOfFood_id; ?></td>
            <td class="foodName"><?php echo $row->kindOfFood_name; ?></td>
            <td><a href="" class="vote">Vote</a></td>

        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

but how can i vote on the right item by clicking the link? 
I know I first have to found the id of the right item but can somebody tell me how to do that ? 
This is how my view looks like, so when I click on the first vote i want to update the chinese. I also displayed the id's with it.

[image]

Somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, There are different ways to build the url...

how about something like this...:

```
<a href="/vote/id/<?php echo $row->kindOfFood_id; ?>" class="vote">Vote</a>
```

Comment: Do I have to do something like this to get the id back in my controller : 

$id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);

Comment: probably, ... try it! In other words: yes

Comment: I tried it, but no result. I'm sorry i'm asking these questions but i'm new to this all.

Comment: I think you should start with learning Zend Framework 2. This is too basic, and if we need to start to explain you everything there is no end. In this case, I'm guessing you are missing the routing setup. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html